# Using AngularJS getterSetter with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

Using AngularJS 1.6 I have a simple input that uses a getter-setter model:

```
<input name="bar" type="number"
    ng-model="dialog.bar" ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}" />
```

The `getterSetter` option means I can have all the values pass through a method in my controller, for validation and/or updating other values, for example:

```
let bar = null;

this.bar = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length) {
    validate(value);
    bar = value;
    update();
  }
  return bar;
}
```

And that works very nicely.

Now I have a `foo` object that has multiple `bar` values inside it. I don't know how many bars there will be. I want to create an input for each bar. The UI is simple enough using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in foo.getBars()">
    <input name="bar{{$index}}" type="number"
        ng-model="dialog.bar" ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}" />
</div>
```

Ah, but how do I link the model back to a getter-setter? I somehow would need to indicate to the getter-setter which `$index` is being used. I could of course use an array of model values directly, but then I wouldn't get the benefit of a getter-setter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea I've come up with so far is to use an array of getter-setters. Then the model looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in foo.getBars()">
    <input name="bar{{$index}}" type="number"
        ng-model="dialog.bars[$index]" ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}" />
</div>
```

Then for each `bars[x]` I simply create a separate function that each remembers the `$index` using closure via  normal loop:

```
const bars = Array(max).fill(0); //values

this.bars = Array(max); //getter-setter functions
for(let i=0; i<max; i++) {
  this.bars[i] = function(value) {
    if (arguments.length) {
      validate(value);
      bars[i] = value;
      update();
    }
    return bar;
  }
}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: This wouldn't scale in performance terms since you're creating an unknown number of function calls that can be called 10 times per digest, if that's 10000 inputs, then you're creating 100000 calls per digest. Your digest cycles would collapse soon as well as your app performance. It sounds like you're trying to solve a problem with the incorrect framework feature or the UI can be changed in a different way to help the user solve the task. Also, I might be wrong and you're hitting a very challenging problem, in which case the performance consideration still applies.